# If / Else GoTo VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Very new to VBA.  Tried searching to no avail.  I have the following code:

```
monsterRollingForHit: rollForMonsterHit = (Int(2 * Rnd))
MsgBox rollForMonsterHit, 0, "Monster Hit Roll"
If rollForMonsterHit = 1 Then
    GoTo monsterRollingForDmg
Else
    GoTo playerRollingForHit
End If

'if monster hits we then roll for his base damage
'using a working around for randBetween due to Analysis Toolpak being required for that     function
monsterRollingForDmg: rollForMonsterDmg = ((Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)))
MsgBox rollForMonsterDmg, 0, "Monster Dmg Roll"
GoTo monsterRollingForCrit

'we then add crit if the monster critically hits
monsterRollingForCrit: rollForMonsterCrit = (rollForMonsterDmg + ((Int(2 * Rnd)) * 8))
MsgBox rollForMonsterCrit, 0, "Monster Crit Roll"
GoTo rollingForPlayerArmor

'finally we reduce the monster's dmg with potential crit by the player's armor
rollingForPlayerArmor: finalMonsterDmg = (rollForMonsterCrit * (((Int((26 * Rnd) + 75)))     / 100))
MsgBox finalMonsterDmg, 0, "Monster Final Dmg"
GoTo reducePlayerHealth

reducePlayerHealth: currentPlayerHP = (currentPlayerHP - finalMonsterDmg)
MsgBox currentPlayerHP, 0, "Current Player HP"
If currentPlayerHP > 0 Then
    GoTo playerRollingForHit
Else
    MsgBox "Monster Wins"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The problem is that even on a rollForMonsterHit value of 0 it never goes to playerRollingForHit.  Instead it just rolls until it gets a 1 and then proceeds.

Problem: Need way to skip a body of code for the Else condition

Comment: Thats not enough code you need to show where is monsterrollingfordmg and playerrollingforhit

Comment: your code is a mess, are you sure you know how does goto works? try avoiding goto, I only use that line in emergencies but it is always better ways to do it, I personally dont like it, because it is really hard to read your code

Comment: the problem is that you are looping so wired, try making subs for each go to you are using

Comment: Thanks all.  I slashed this and rewrote into a do loop that is doing what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Use of `Option Explicit` helps with finding typo's in variable names.

this would be the psedo-code for what you appear to be trying. also notice that there are no goto's or labels.

```
Set MonsterHP and HeroHP
while monsterHP>0 and HeroHP>0
    if MonsterHit then
        work out monsterdmg
        decide if critical
        deduct from heroHP, accounting for any armor/dodge/etc
    endif
    if HeroHit then
        work out HeroDmg
        decide if critical
        deduct from MonsterHP, accounting for any armor/dodge/etc
    endif
wend
if monsterdmg>0 then
    print "Monster Wins"
elseif heroHP>0 then
    print "Hero wins"
else
    print "They killed each other with their final blow!"
endif
```

Comment: Very good idea to show the program flow in block format. I used it as the input to my demo program; I think between the two answers, OP should get a better idea of how to create games like this.

Comment: @augusthippo, `while ... wend` is a valid loop in vba, but `do ... until monsterHP<0 or HeroHP<0` would work too

Answer (score 1):

You did not define the label `playerRollingForHit`... at least not in the code you are showing. This is a problem.

As was pointed out by others, not having an idea of code structure is a much bigger problem. A `GoTo` statement, while legal should be used sparingly. And you should consider making your code more re-usable.  For example, you can create your own data type:

```
Public Type player
  health As Integer
  strength As Integer
  ' whatever other properties you might have...
End Type
```

And then you can create an array of players:

```
Dim players( 1 To 2 ) as player
```

This means you will be able to loop over the players, and "player 1 attacks player 2" can use the same code as "player 2 attacks player 1" (if they have the same rules). Similarly, you might want to create your own function "rollBetween" which allows you to roll different dice with a simple instruction.

```
Function rollBetween(n1 As Integer, n2 As Integer)
' roll a number between n1 and n2, inclusive
rollBetween = Round(Rnd * (n2 - n1 + 1) - 0.5, 0) + n1
End Function
```

Putting it all together, for fun, I created some code that may help you understand what I'm talking about. Note - the rules here are not the same rules you used, but it's the same principle; as players get more strength, they become more immune to attack, and their attacks become stronger. I hope you can learn something from it, and have fun creating your game!

```
Option Explicit

Public Type player
  health As Integer
  strength As Integer
End Type

Sub monsters()
' main program loop
' can have more than two players: just change dimension of array
' and rules of "who attacks whom"
Dim players(1 To 2) As player
Dim attacker As Integer
Dim defender As Integer

initPlayers players
attacker = rollBetween(1, 2) ' who goes first: player 1 or 2
Debug.Print "Player " & attacker & " gets the first roll"

While stillAlive(players)
  defender = (attacker Mod 2) + 1
  playTurn players, attacker, defender
  attacker = defender  ' person who was attacked becomes the attacker
Wend

MsgBox winner(players())

End Sub

'------------------------------
' functions that support the main program loop 'monsters':

Function rollBetween(n1 As Integer, n2 As Integer)
' roll a number between n1 and n2, inclusive
rollBetween = Round(Rnd * (n2 - n1 + 1) - 0.5, 0) + n1
End Function

Sub initPlayers(ByRef p() As player)
' initialize the strength of the players etc
Dim ii
For ii = LBound(p) To UBound(p)
  p(ii).health = 10
  p(ii).strength = 1
Next

End Sub

Function stillAlive(p() As player) As Boolean
' see whether players are still alive
' returns false if at least one player's health is less than 0
Dim ii
For ii = LBound(p) To UBound(p)
  If p(ii).health <= 0 Then
    stillAlive = False
    Exit Function
  End If
Next ii
stillAlive = True
End Function

Sub playTurn(ByRef p() As player, n As Integer, m As Integer)
' attack of player(n) on player(m)
Dim roll As Integer

' see if you can attack, or just heal:
roll = rollBetween(1, 2)
Debug.Print "player " & n & " rolled a " & roll

If roll = 1 Then
  ' roll for damage
  roll = rollBetween(1, 4 + p(n).strength)  ' as he gets stronger, attacks become more damaging
  Debug.Print "player " & n & " rolled a " & roll & " for attack"
  If p(m).strength > roll Then
    p(n).strength = p(n).strength - 1 ' attacker gets weaker because attack failed
    p(m).strength = p(m).strength + 2 ' defender gets stronger
  Else
    p(n).strength = p(n).strength + 1 ' attacker gains strength
    p(m).health = p(m).health - roll  ' defender loses health
  End If
Else
  ' roll for healing
  roll = rollBetween(1, 3)
  Debug.Print "player " & n & " rolled a " & roll & " for health"
  p(n).health = p(n).health + roll
End If
Debug.Print "statistics now: " & p(1).health & "," & p(1).strength & ";" & p(2).health & "," & p(2).strength

End Sub

Function winner(p() As player)
Dim ii, h, w
' track player with higher health:
h = 0
w = 0

For ii = LBound(p) To UBound(p)
  If p(ii).health > h Then
    w = ii
    h = p(ii).health
  End If
Next ii

winner = "Player " & w & " is the winner!"

End Function
```

Output of a typical game might be:

```
Player 2 gets the first roll
player 2 rolled a 2
player 2 rolled a 2 for health
statistics now: 10,1;12,1
player 1 rolled a 1
player 1 rolled a 2 for attack
statistics now: 10,2;10,1
player 2 rolled a 2
player 2 rolled a 1 for health
statistics now: 10,2;11,1
player 1 rolled a 2
player 1 rolled a 3 for health
statistics now: 13,2;11,1
player 2 rolled a 2
player 2 rolled a 1 for health
statistics now: 13,2;12,1
player 1 rolled a 1
player 1 rolled a 6 for attack
statistics now: 13,3;6,1
player 2 rolled a 2
player 2 rolled a 2 for health
statistics now: 13,3;8,1
player 1 rolled a 2
player 1 rolled a 3 for health
statistics now: 16,3;8,1
player 2 rolled a 1
player 2 rolled a 5 for attack
statistics now: 11,3;8,2
player 1 rolled a 1
player 1 rolled a 4 for attack
statistics now: 11,4;4,2
player 2 rolled a 2
player 2 rolled a 1 for health
statistics now: 11,4;5,2
player 1 rolled a 2
player 1 rolled a 2 for health
statistics now: 13,4;5,2
player 2 rolled a 1
player 2 rolled a 4 for attack
statistics now: 9,4;5,3
player 1 rolled a 2
player 1 rolled a 1 for health
statistics now: 10,4;5,3
player 2 rolled a 1
player 2 rolled a 6 for attack
statistics now: 4,4;5,4
player 1 rolled a 2
player 1 rolled a 2 for health
statistics now: 6,4;5,4
player 2 rolled a 2
player 2 rolled a 3 for health
statistics now: 6,4;8,4
player 1 rolled a 1
player 1 rolled a 6 for attack
statistics now: 6,5;2,4
player 2 rolled a 2
player 2 rolled a 1 for health
statistics now: 6,5;3,4
player 1 rolled a 2
player 1 rolled a 1 for health
statistics now: 7,5;3,4
player 2 rolled a 2
player 2 rolled a 3 for health
statistics now: 7,5;6,4
player 1 rolled a 1
player 1 rolled a 6 for attack
statistics now: 7,6;0,4
```

Final output - message box that declares player 1 the winner.

Comment: the name of one of your functions, `StillAlive` always reminds me of that song. Evidently it's a little too tenuous a link

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead: `monsterRollingForHit: rollForMonsterHit = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(2 * Rnd(), 0)`

Answer (score -3):

```
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
  If Worksheets(i).Name = "Table B" Or Worksheets(i).Name = "Table C" Then GoTo line1
  If Worksheets(i).Name = "Table N" Then GoTo line3
  If Worksheets(i).Name = "Table O" Then GoTo line2
Next i
```

Comment: How is this fixing the issue?